# WinApi: IO Completion Ports

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Explain, please:

From MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports#supported-io-functions

> Consider what happens with a concurrency value of one and multiple
> threads waiting in the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function call. In
> this case, if the queue always has completion packets waiting, when
> the running thread calls GetQueuedCompletionStatus, it will not block
> execution because, as mentioned earlier, the thread queue is LIFO.
> Instead, this thread will immediately pick up the next queued
> completion packet. No thread context switches will occur, because the
> running thread is continually picking up completion packets and the
> **other threads** are unable to run.

I don’t understand what other threads are we talking about?

PS: Sorry for such a simple and stupid question. I'm really confused.

Comment: Link please. Also, what part exactly is unclear? Which parts are clear?

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports#supported-io-functions.  I cannot understand what OTHER thread are written about. In the quote from the MSDN, it is highlighted in bold.

Comment: Add that link to your question, you can [edit] it still. In any case, aren't those other threads the ones mentioned in the first quoted sentence?

Comment: other threads , which call GetQueuedCompletionStatus (wait for packets) on same iocp

Comment: @RbMm, and then why do we need other streams, if they "are unable to run." ? Or I still don't understand something.

Comment: but if more packets exist in iocp ? of course many threads can pop packet and run. depend from packet count in port and *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* for this port

Comment: you drop first sentence, which is very important in context - *The most efficient scenario occurs when there are completion packets waiting in the queue, but no waits can be satisfied because the **port has reached its concurrency limit** .*

Comment: other threads are unable to run - when port has reached its concurrency limit - only for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using the extreme example of NumberOfConcurrentThreads  set to 1 but still having multiple threads calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus. It is saying that under those circumstances (that of there always being a packet queued) the first thread to return a packet will simply continue returning packets and the other threads waiting in GetQueuedCompletionStatus will continue waiting.